# Old scaled data fail to disappear after axis rescale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3 ver 3.5.5. I am using an example (https://gist.github.com/stepheneb/1182434) as a template: the example code to draw the data looks like this:

```
  var circle = this.vis.select("svg").selectAll("circle")
      .data(this.points, function(d) { return d; });

  circle.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d === self.selected ? "selected" : null; })
      .attr("cx",    function(d) { return self.x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy",    function(d) { return self.y(d.y); })
      .attr("r", 10.0)
      .style("cursor", "ns-resize")
      .on("mousedown.drag",  self.datapoint_drag())
      .on("touchstart.drag", self.datapoint_drag());

  circle
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d === self.selected ? "selected" : null; })
      .attr("cx",    function(d) { 
        return self.x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy",    function(d) { return self.y(d.y); });

  circle.exit().remove();
```

I think of this as four sections: the first does selectAll("circles") and adds the data. The second tells where the data points are ("cx", "cy") and other attr(), and the third is a bit of mystery to me, because it appears to also set "cx" and "cy", but no other attributes. Finally, we do and exit().remove(), which the documentation says removes any data elements not associated with the data array. I dont see how this is happening in this example. When I set breakpoints into the code, both the "cx" steps get called for each data point in the this.points array.

In my code, I try to do the same steps:

```
hr_circles = self.graph_gps.svg.selectAll("hr_circles")
        .data(self.graph_gps.datay1); // , function(d){return d;}

hr_circles.enter().append("circle")
        .style("z-index", 3)
        .attr("class", "y1")
        .attr("r", 1)
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
          return xScale(d.time)
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
          return yScale(d.vy)
        })
        .on("mouseover",
                function (d) {...displays a tooltip...})
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        });

  hr_circles.attr("class", "y1")
          .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
            return xScale(d.time)
          })
          .attr("cy", function (d, i) {
            return yScale(d.vy)
          })

  hr_circles.exit().remove();
```

When my graph initially displays, the data appear just fine, properly scaled, etc. When I try to re-scale by dragging on the x-axis (as in the example), the axis rescales itself just fine, and re-scaled data appears on the graph, but the original data is also still there (no longer scaled correctly), making a big mess! How do you erase or make the originally scaled data go away?
Tried to post images, but I guess my reputation is too low. Will send to anyone interested.

Comment: How did you implement the dragging?

Comment: Oh wait, the problem is that you're selecting `hr_circles` elements which never exist. Your selection is always empty. Select the `circle` elements like in the example.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I followed the example. Also, the data appear just fine before I try to rescale so how can hr_circles be empty? Why do you think it is empty? My code first creates hr_circles with a selectAll().data(), then on the object created, it calls enter().append(), and I think that usually adds data, does it not? This is same as the example, unless I am missing something (likely, since it doesnt work!!).

Comment: I am not showing the dragging, because that appears to work, and it was implemented much like the example. User grabs an x-axis tick label, drags it over, and on release, the axis rescales, the data appear properly scaled, but the old data image stays on the graph. Getting rid of the old data image is the problem.

Comment: One difference between my code and example, is he uses selectAll("circle"), whereas I use selectAll("hr_circles"). I thought the argument to selectAll is just a name, you can use anything, but maybe I am wrong about that?

Comment: No, you can't use anything -- the argument to `.selectAll()` tells D3 what you want to select (`circle` elements in your case). If you select something that doesn't exist, your selection will always be empty and update won't work. See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) for more information.